# How to change subscription status after authentication only !! in stripe 3d secure subscription

Tags: security, subscription, 3d-secure, stripe-payments

I subscribed to a plane with 5 days trial period with test card number 4000 0027 6000 3184. It appears a pop up window
[image]

still now so far so good. Now I looked my stripe dash board , it shows the status trial ends..
[image]

But I neither authenticate the card nor cancel the authentication .
So my question is , how to change the status to incomplete if I do not authenticate the card??

Comment: You can't. The subscription will only become `incomplete` if an initial payment failed — when there's a trial, there's been no payment, you're just authenticating to 'set up' success for the eventual payment when the trial ends. If you didn't authenticate then there's more chance of a payment failure at that point and you handle it like any other recurring payment failure. 
Or you can follow https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/payment#authorization-failures — you use the subscription's SetupIntent and can track when it fails.

Comment: Thank you.
If I use same card for payment with proper authentication for another subscription(no trial period), at that moment what will be happened for previous subscription(with trial period) when trial perod ends ?

Comment: That really depends on the bank, there isn't a definitive answer. If you as a merchant have charged the card with authentication before, you _might_ have a better chance of not having to authenticate it again on the other subscription. But you can't assume that, just build your integration to be able to handle all cases where a payment might need authentication, since it's always a possibility.